# Неправильное отображение цены в Google play services

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

Подключил покупки, наблюдается следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по ценам в консоли разработчика все в порядке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по курсу валют совпадает с тем, что указывал. Из списка цен по странам нету таких чисел, в чем может быть дело?

Может это какой-то Австралийский доллар?

У меня пока нету информации о том, откуда сделан скриншот, предполагаемо из Молдовы.

Comment: видимо, в финальную стоимость добавлен налог

Answer (score 0):

Где-то в настройках продуктов, точно сейчас не вспомню, есть чекбокс - является ли указанная вами стоимость за товары "итоговой" ценой - т.е. включены ли в неё все налоги на продажу этих товаров, или гугл будет их сам добавлять при совершении операции.

Похоже, что у вас цены указаны "без налогов" и гугл сам накидывает их для конечного покупателя.

Более подробно можете узнать [в статье самого гугла](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138000). Там указано, где находятся эти настройки